# 4TB disk connected via eSATA not working properly

Tags: windows, hard-drive, sata, esata

My System:

- Mainboard: ASUS P9X79
- eSATA controller: Asmedia 106x (onboard). Driver version: 1.4.1.0
- OS: Windows 8.1 pro x64
- PyroGate external drive cage for 3.5" HDD containing a 4TB disk from WD. The cage provides an eSATA and USB port, but the eSATA one is used of course ;)
- Disk is using GPT layout, **not** MBR.

When i connect the external HDD cage to the eSATA port, i have problems formatting the disk. It looks like it takes forever.

Looking in the eventvwr reveals, that there is a problem with the disk:

```
The IO operation at logical block address 0 for Disk 3 (PDO name: \Device\Ide\IdeDeviceP0T0L0-57) was retried.
```

After ~10 mins quick-formatting a 1 GB partition (yes, 1 GB) it is ready to use. When i copy some files on the disk, i get the same eventlog entries. Same when i'm reading from the disk.

When i remove the disk from the cage and attach it to an internal SATA PORT it works fine. Meaning i can format the disk, read & write from and to it withouht having these warnings in the event log.

What could be the reason for it? Does the Asmedia controller have some problems which such big disks? Or could it be my external HDD cage?

BTW: Previously, i had a 2TB disk in the drive cage and it worked just fine!

Comment: See: [Tried to use my 3TB drive in a USB enclosure, now reports only 746GB even internally](http://superuser.com/questions/281108/tried-to-use-my-3tb-drive-in-a-usb-enclosure-now-reports-only-746gb-even-intern), then try a new enclosure.

Comment: not entirely the same. diskpart.exe always shows a 4 TB disk

Comment: But it points out that some enclosures are known to not support the drive sizes properly.  You suspect the enclosure, the drive works other wise, so unless you can find a firmware upgrade for that enclosure (I doubt one exists), it's time to try a new enclosure (that specifically states it can handle the >2TB size drives).

Comment: BTW: also ensure your chipset and hard drive controller drivers are up-to-date (from their respective manufacturers).